# Docker Compose Containers cannot access each other

Tags: docker-compose, smtp, nginx-reverse-proxy, mailcow

I have three docker compose containers set up behind a nginx reverse-proxy, namely Mailcow, Nextcloud AIO and GitLab. I want to use Mailcow as the SMTP server for GitLab and Nextcloud, but both containers cannot connect to mail.domain.com:587, something that works fine outside the containers. How can i get the containers to connect?

I have already tried to create a shared network between the containers by adding `mailcowdockerized_mailcow-network` as external network to Nextcloud and GitLab, but with no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use the container ID instead of the domain name

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).